# Send data of form to div on submitting , outside the form using jQuery, laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

this is my form

```
      <form method="post" action="{{url('/vpage')}}"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

      <label>First Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="{{$user->firstname}}" >

      <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"  value="{{$user->email}}" >

      <label>Phone Number <span> (optional)</span></label>
             <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="(888) 888-888" value="{{$user->phone}}" >

      <button id="hitme" class="submitBTN getstart" type="submit" onclick='return false;'> Get Started </button> 
       </form>
```

this is div outside the form

```
   <div class="vgasRit">
        <p>SUMMARY</p>
           <div class="sfieldz w100">

              <label>Name:</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" value="{{$user->firstname}}">

          </div>
          <div class="w100">
              <label>Email Address:</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="johnsmith@gmail.com" value="{{$user->email}}" >
           </div>

            <div class="w100">
               <label>Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="(888) 888-888" value="{{$user->phone}}">
             </div>
    </div>
```

I want to access the value of the "fistname" , "lastname" and "phone" as user submit the form,so that i can display it in summary div.

**Note:** i have tried compact function of php in my controller so that i can send the whole database object in my view but this solution not working , after using compact function i was access the object like this

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith"  value="<?= (!empty($group_data)) ? $group_data->firstname : '';?>">
```

Any ideas regarding this ? i am new to laravel. I have served several hours on internet but nothing found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything is on the same page, give your form's inputs an id:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="{{url('/vpage')}}"> 
<label>First Name</label>
       <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="{{$user->firstname}}" >

  <label>Email Address</label>
      <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"  value="{{$user->email}}" >

  <label>Phone Number <span> (optional)</span></label>
         <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="(888) 888-888" value="{{$user->phone}}" >
```

Give your summary div inputs an id too:

```
<p>SUMMARY</p>
       <div class="sfieldz w100">

          <label>Name:</label>
          <input id="firstname2" type="text" placeholder="John Smith" value="{{$user->firstname}}">

      </div>
      <div class="w100">
          <label>Email Address:</label>
          <input id="email2" type="text" placeholder="johnsmith@gmail.com" value="{{$user->email}}" >
       </div>

        <div class="w100">
           <label>Phone Number:</label>
        <input id="phone2" type="text" placeholder="(888) 888-888" value="{{$user->phone}}">
         </div>
```

Then, use jquery to get those values when the user submits the form:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    // set our summary div inputs values with our form values
    $('firstname2').val($('firstname').val());
    $('email2').val($('email').val());
    $('phone2').val($('phone').val());
});
```

That should be it.

Comment: is there any need to specify the value of the summary div input fields ?

Comment: You want to get your form values when the user submits, and then set your div inputs values to those values, right? If everything is on the same page, you only need some javascript to achieve this.

Comment: does form and summery DIV in same view ?

Answer (score 1):

Your view (I assumed that form and summery div in same view):

```
        <form method="post" action="{{url('/vpage')}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="{{$user->firstname}}">

            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="{{$user->email}}">

            <label>Phone Number <span> (optional)</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="(888) 888-888" value="{{$user->phone}}">

            <button id="hitme" class="submitBTN getstart" type="submit" onclick='return false;'> Get Started</button>
        </form>


@if($Data->input('firstname'))
      <p>SUMMARY</p>


           <div class="sfieldz w100">

              <label>Name:</label>
              <input id="firstname2" type="text" placeholder="John Smith" value="{{$Data->input('firstname')}}">

          </div>
          <div class="w100">
              <label>Email Address:</label>
              <input id="email2" type="text" placeholder="johnsmith@gmail.com" value="{{$Data->input('email')}}" >
           </div>

            <div class="w100">
               <label>Phone Number:</label>
            <input id="phone2" type="text" placeholder="(888) 888-888" value="{{$Data->input('phone')}}">
             </div>

@endif
```

Contoroller

```
function vpageController(Request $r){
  return view("path.to.view",['Data'=>$r]);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::Route::match(['POST', 'GET'],'/vpage', 'ControllerName@vpageController');
```